# Cannot get RestKit to work in Xcode 4.6

Tags: xcode, ios6, restkit

I'm trying to get RestKit to work but I keep getting an error, this is Xcode 4.6 and the target iOS is 6.1

I'm following this guide:

https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Installing-RestKit-v0.20.x-as-a-Git-Submodule

The error I get is:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386: 
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_RKClient", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

One of the things that differs between the guide and my Xcode is that the file libRestKit.a is nowhere to be seen, the only option is RestKit (see screenshots below of my xcode)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9jVC.png

I'm probably missing something very simple but I can't figure out what

Thanks in advance

Comment: yes, it's 0.2. I tried installing using CocoaPods but there were issues too. I'll try again and I'll let you know. Thanks

Comment: Thanks Zaph. I tried again using CocoaPods and managed to get it working now. I never used RestKit before so I guess it's better to start with 0.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using version 0.2 of RestKit try installing with CocoaPods.

0.2 is a world of hurt right now especially if you have experience with 0.1 or earlier. Many methods disappeared with no good way to find their replacements. The docs still have 0.1 examples and documentation that is no longer correct in 0.2.

NSScreencast has a couple videos on 0.2, very nicely done.

Hopefully the documentation will be updated soon.